# Images from database not showing on Blade view

Tags: php, database, laravel, image, laravel-blade

```html
<td>
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$a->image) }}" alt="{{ $a->image }}" class="img-fluid" width="50%">
</td>
```

And I'm facing this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Run a dd($a->image) to see what the output is.

Then open up your browser and see if it connects.

http://yoursite.test/storage/whateverYourImageNameIs.jpg

If it doesn't work, did you run the symbolic link?

```
php artisan storage:link
```

If it still doesn't work look at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Comment: I have run php artisan storage:link already but it doesn't work . I'm shocked that my project was running 100% accurate I just turned off my PC then turn on and I'm facing this error.

Comment: dd($a->image) it gives the output of path of the stored image but when I'm going to show it in my user pages then it is showing me this error.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you are running in Windows. Which I used to have so many problems with permissions, etc.

Comment: What error do you get when you run storage:link?

Comment: yes I'm running it in windows first time when I ran it, it was running perfectly but now everything from database is shown but image is not shown it simply showing the path of image uploads/jaadag.png something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
$url = Storage::url($a->image);
<td>
    <img src="{{ $url }}" alt="{{ $url }}" class="img-fluid" width="50%">
</td>
```

Comment: I don't know what is problem I have been working for a long time on projects I just modified my laptop by changing its RAM and M1 card and I installed the setups project was running perfect for a long time but suddenly it shows this error. Every of the project is giving this error.

Comment: Can you tell me where the image is located in laravel?

Comment: You can try again
$url = Storage::disk('public')->url($a->image);